# Long loops in critical random graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-graphs

A simple calculation seems to show that the expected number $X_k$ of loops of length $k$ in a critical Erdös-Renyi random graph $G(n,n^{-1})$ is approximately given by

$$ \mathbb{E} X_k=\frac1{2k}{e^{-\frac{k^2}{2n}}}$$

(see e.g. (5.4) in "[On the evolution of random graph](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a5aa/d5abb32f6b15f31b92312bb3b0f7b6470977.pdf)" for $G(N,N/2)$).

However in the scaling limit of the largest components only loops of length $O(n^{\frac13})$ are present (see Addario-Berry et al.) leaving the questions where the long loops are.

This seems to indicate that with probability $o(1)$ there is a (large) component that contains very many long loops. Is this correct and is anything known about this event?